# unabel to locate element from JSON file

Tags: json, web-services, automation, karate

I am using karate automation tool for service automation.. and i am trying to extract department id from the json response which i have stored in variable ...

def departmentId = getstorewalk.departments[*].id

getstorewalk is my variable in which json response is stored

following is the json response

{"walkzz":"001","zz":zz,"ddd":"zz","zz":{"zz":"zz","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}},"departments":[{"id":need to extract this id,"name":"zz","someorder":1,"zzs":[{"zz":zz,"name":"zz (zz, zz, zz, zz & zz)","someorder":zz,"zz":[{"zz":51,"name":"zz Spread","someorder":16,"zz":"Available","zz":[{"zz":"1223","zz":"zz 30g","zz":3,"zz":0,"zz":"stale","zz":false,"zz":true,"zz":[],"zz":{"zz":2,"zz":"zz","zz":6,"zzName":"Core zz (zz)","department":56,"zz":"015 zz Spreads","zz":"zz Spread","subzz":100,"somezz":"zz & zz","zz":{},"zz_":100},"zz":{"zz":"2017-09-21T11:09:15.524Z","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}},"action":{"zz":"Include"},"zz":[{"capturezz":375716,"zz":"Gap","qty":15,"zz":"zz","zz":{"zz":"zz","type":"N","name":"zz","sequence":1},"zz":{"zz":"211","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}}}]}]}]}]}]}

i have used the following in the background :

- def getstorewalk = callonce read('classpath:zz/zz/zz.feature')
- def departmentId = getstorewalk.departments[*].id

and error is listed below:
com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['departments']
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:72)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:77)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:164)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:151)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.evalJsonPathOnVarByName(Script.java:339)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:262)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.eval(Script.java:182)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:606)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.assign(Script.java:537)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.def(StepDefs.java:268)
    at ?.* def departmentId = getstorewalk.departments[*].id(C:/Karate/zz/zz/src/test/java/zz/zz/zz.feature:11)

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me, you can try paste the 3 lines below in a Karate file. By the way this is a good tip for troubleshooting, you can test snippets like this without needing to make HTTP calls.

```
* def getstorewalk = {"walkzz":"001","zz":zz,"ddd":"zz","zz":{"zz":"zz","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}},"departments":[{"id":need to extract this id,"name":"zz","someorder":1,"zzs":[{"zz":zz,"name":"zz (zz, zz, zz, zz & zz)","someorder":zz,"zz":[{"zz":51,"name":"zz Spread","someorder":16,"zz":"Available","zz":[{"zz":"1223","zz":"zz 30g","zz":3,"zz":0,"zz":"stale","zz":false,"zz":true,"zz":[],"zz":{"zz":2,"zz":"zz","zz":6,"zzName":"Core zz (zz)","department":56,"zz":"015 zz Spreads","zz":"zz Spread","subzz":100,"somezz":"zz & zz","zz":{},"zz_":100},"zz":{"zz":"2017-09-21T11:09:15.524Z","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}},"action":{"zz":"Include"},"zz":[{"capturezz":375716,"zz":"Gap","qty":15,"zz":"zz","zz":{"zz":"zz","type":"N","name":"zz","sequence":1},"zz":{"zz":"211","who":{"zz":"11","zz":"zz"}}}]}]}]}]}]}
* def departmentId = getstorewalk.departments[*].id
* print departmentId
```

which logs:

```
19:40:55.135 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] ["need to extract this id"]
```

So, clearly you have made a mistake assigning the response to `getstorewalk`.

My guess is you intended to do this:

```
def result = callonce read('classpath:zz/zz/zz.feature')
def departmentId = result.response.departments[*].id
```

Please read the documentation on calling other feature files carefully and you will probably realize what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Peter ..thank you for the response ..but i need to take response from another request and pass department id from it to next request... and hence i need to call the first feature file for the response(department id)... you are directly storing json file in the variable .. and hence it is working . .. i think i am making mistake in calling the response and storing it to variable .. ur solution is working in case you are directly storing response in  getstorewalk ... how do i call the feature file ..and store its json response to getstorewalk ??

Comment: @TanajiPadwal did you even read the last 6 lines of my answer !? try again.